# Updating a data property in Vuejs based on an input event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a search input that filters data. The filtered data is meant to re-render my page so that the original property(`shifts`) will now have the filtered data and this means any change in the search input should update my data object. The snippet below works perfectly so that when I monitor the logged variable `filteredData` I can see its returning the expected data. When I type on the search input the data is filtered as expected and when I clear the search, the object contains the data in the original `shifts` property.

The issue occurs when I assign this filtered data to my original object i.e. `this.shifts=filteredData`. When I do this, the `shifts` property will contain the filtered data but when I clear the search the previously filtered data is what will still be assigned meaning that the `shifts` property is not being properly updated. Not sure why this is happening.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      search_input: '',
      shifts: {"John":[{"user_id":193,"shift_hours":0}],"Rose":[{"user_id":194,"shift_hours":0}]},
  },
  
  methods: {
    searchInput() {
      const filteredData = Object.keys(this.shifts).reduce(
    (obj, key) => {
      if (
        key.toLowerCase().includes(this.search_input.toLowerCase())
      ) {
        obj[key] = this.shifts[key];
      }

      return obj;
    },
    {}
  );

  console.log(filteredData);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<input v-model="search_input" @input.prevent="searchInput" type="text"/>
</div>
```

I've appended an additional snippet below to showcase the issue I'm facing:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      search_input: '',
      shifts: {"John":[{"user_id":193,"shift_hours":0}],"Rose":[{"user_id":194,"shift_hours":0}]},
  },
  
  methods: {
    searchInput() {
      const filteredData = Object.keys(this.shifts).reduce(
        (obj, key) => {
          if (key.toLowerCase().includes(this.search_input.toLowerCase())) {
            obj[key] = this.shifts[key];
          }

          return obj;
        },
        {}
      );

      this.shifts = filteredData;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="search_input" @input.prevent="searchInput" type="text" />

  <pre>{{ shifts }}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Data needs to be a function, and you can use computed property for filtering:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      search_input: '',
      shifts: {"John": [{"user_id": 193, "shift_hours": 0}], "Rose": [{"user_id": 194, "shift_hours": 0}]},
    }
  },
  computed: {
    searchInput() {
      return Object.keys(this.shifts).reduce((obj, key) => {
        if (key.toLowerCase().includes(this.search_input.toLowerCase())) {
          obj[key] = this.shifts[key]
        }
        return obj
      }, {} )
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="search_input" type="text" />
  <pre>{{ searchInput }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Since my use case is constarined to a user input to trigger the filtering of the data, do you have a solution in mind that we can implement based on user input?

Comment: @suo hey mate, sorry but I didn't get what you mean. In current solution filtering is triggered by typing in search input.

Comment: Ok. What i mean is since I need the shifts property to be updated on filter, was thinking the only way possible was using an input event then assign the filtered data to the shifts property. The updated shifts property will then prompt a re-render on the DOM with the new data.

Comment: Hello mate. You have any idea how to approach this?